# Perl flock does not work from CGI

Tags: perl, locking, cgi

(Before running the below script replace /home/porton/t/MOVE with a path to a file you have the right to create or erase.)

When I start this script from the command line and during 10 secs start the same script from command line again, it prints what I expect:

```
Flock: 1
```

and

```
Flock: 0
```

correspondingly.

But when I run it twice (with interval between the time of the requests less than 10 secs) as CGI that is as http://test.localhost/cgi-bin/test2.pl it prints

```
Flock: 1
```

for both two CGI requests.

What is the error? Why it behaves in a different unexpected way when run from CGI?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Fcntl qw(:flock);

print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";

open(my $lock_fh, '>', "/home/porton/t/MOVE");

print "Flock: " . flock($lock_fh, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB) . "\n";

sleep 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the two requests are running in parallel? They might be handled sequentially, i.e. the second request could be processed after the first one is completed, and after the lock has been released.

Comment: I use Apache/2.2.16 on Debian Linux. I wonder if it may handle requests sequentially. How to check this?

Comment: Have your script print out timestamps before and after locking/sleeping. If they're running sequentially you'll get a "before / after / before / after" pattern, if they're parallel you'll get a "before / before / after / after" pattern.